# Problemas con el stylesheet de Chrome

Tags: css, html5

Estoy intentando rotar un video que se encuentra en pantalla completa en Chrome, pero está resultando ser imposible. Intenté con transform: rotate(180deg) !important, pero solo funciona mientras el video no está en pantalla completa.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
como pueden observar, se supone que ´logré´ sobreescribir el estilo del user agent stylesheet, pero el video a pantalla competa sigue sin rotarse. ¿Alguna idea de qué pueda estar haciendo mal?
Gracias de antemano.

Edit: Actualicé la foto y organicé mejor el código

Código de los estilos:

```css
    .flip-video, .flip-video:fullscreen, 
    .flip-video::-webkit-media-controls-panel {
            
        transform: rotate(180deg) !important;
        transform-origin: center;
    }
```

En el body:

```
    <video  controls  preload="metadata" class="flip-video">
        <source src="./9ee44195-f7cc-495f-b69d-15e7c56fc476.mp4" 
        type="video/mp4">
    </video>
```

Answer (score 2):

No es fácil decir exactamente qué no funciona en tu código a partir de una sola imagen. Pero puedes usar `object-fit: cover` y `height: 100vw; width: 100%;` para rotar el video y hacerlo a pantalla completa.

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
}

video {
  position: absolute;
  transform: rotate(180deg);
  height: 100vw;
  width: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
}
```

```html
<video id="gato" src="http://html5demos.com/assets/dizzy.mp4" autoplay loop></video>
```

Comment: Gracias @milmal, pero realmente quisiera transformar el video al pasar a pantalla completa usando el botón de los controles por defecto. Voy a actualizar la pregunta con el código de los estilos, si pudieras echarle un vistazo sería de gran ayuda.

Comment: Ay, no se si es posible :/